# When is the TCP receive window advertised?

Tags: networking, tcp

I am trying to learn about the TCP 3 way handshake and flow control. I was reading [this](https://www.guru99.com/tcp-3-way-handshake.html) and I understand that in the 3 way handshake the sender and receiver agree on the Sequence and Acknowledgement numbers.

Also, [this](https://www.brianstorti.com/tcp-flow-control/) article mentions that the receive window is advertised when the connection is made :

*Let’s say we want to send a 150000 bytes file from node A to node B. TCP could break this file down into 100 packets, 1500 bytes each. Now let’s say that when the connection between node A and B is established, node B advertises a receive window of 45000 bytes, because it really wants to help us with our math here.*

My question is when is the receive window established for the first time? Is it *during* the 3 way handshake or *after* the 3 way handshake?

Comment: It's set by the application before the handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Is it during the 3 way handshake or after the 3 way handshake?

It's set by the application before the handshake:

> Applications determine the initial window size and you can see this
>   size for each device at the initial synchronisation (the three-way
>   handshake). Windows uses 8760 bytes for Ethernet by default, although
>   this can be changed in the registry. The number 8760 is 6 x 1460 which
>   is the amount of data a full Ethernet frame can carry and is the MSS
>   for Ethernet by default, which is shared during the synchronisation.
>   When sizing a window, 6-8 times the packet size is considered the most
>   efficient. In the old days of the Internet (early 1980s) when
>   protocols such as X.25 were prevalent, users were often advised to
>   assume a much smaller datagram size of 576 (from RFC 791), although no
>   longer necessary, you may come across smaller MSS and window size
>   settings as a result.
>
> The less errors that occur on the network, the larger the window is
>   allowed to get and the more bandwidth is used for data. The only
>   problem with a large window size is that if there is a transmission
>   failure at any point, the whole segment has to be resent thereby
>   taking up bandwidth anyway.
>
> One thing to be aware of with TCP protocols is the slow ramping up of
>   the window size. For instance, if you are sending a 10Mb file using
>   FTP, it may take 1Mb of transfer before the transfer occurs at optimum
>   speed. This is because the window size starts off small so that much
>   of the initial traffic is header rather than data. Downloading small
>   files using FTP does not reach the optimum data download speed,
>   downloading large files is more efficient. This mechanism is called
>   Slow Start and is outlined in RFC 2001.

Source [Transfer Control Protocol, 3-way handshake, TCP sliding window](http://www.rhyshaden.com/tcp.htm)